# SOTorrent: Select answers of only those threads which have the "android" tag?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Dataset:** [SOTorrent](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/results/stackoverflow-208006:US.bquijob_6a29d8f7_1664db5aaea?pli=1) -- Here's the dataset (hosted on Google's BigQuery): You can run your queries there and then. It has a Posts table. Although I have tried to explain the concerned fields below, a detailed schema of the **Posts** table can be found here for your reference: [SO Schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/315065)

SO: StackOverflow

**Background:** The datasets has a table called **Posts**. In that table, a field **PostTypeId** exists:

- If that field is 1, it means the post we are looking at right now is a Question posted on SO. In this case, another field called **Tags** will contain the tags assigned by the OP of the question on SO.
- If that field is 2, then it's an answer posted on SO. In this case, the **Tags** field will be Null.

**Problem:** Select all answers of only those threads that have the Android tag attached to them.

**My Solution:**

```
SELECT
 p.Id,
 p.Score,
 p.body
FROM
  [sotorrent-org:2018_09_23.Posts] p
WHERE
  p.Tags LIKE "%android%"
  AND p.PostTypeId = 2 
LIMIT
  10
```

However, it is obvious that the above query will return `null` because the WHERE clause checks for conditions that can't co-exist. If the post has tags, it cannot be an answer. If it is an answer, it can't have tags.

How can I get around this problem and check for two mutually-exclusive conditions on the same Table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the posts table to itself using the `ParentId` field:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  answer.Id
, answer.Score
, answer.body
FROM
  `sotorrent-org.2018_09_23.Posts` question
JOIN
  `sotorrent-org.2018_09_23.Posts` answer
ON
      answer.ParentId=question.Id
  AND answer.PostTypeId=2
  AND question.PostTypeId=1
WHERE
      question.Tags LIKE "%android%"
  AND question.PostTypeId = 1
  AND answer.PostTypeId = 2
LIMIT
  10
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think the best approach is window functions:

```
SELECT p.Id,  p.Score p.body
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             MAX(p.tags) OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(p.parentid, p.id)) as tags
      FROM `sotorrent-org.2018_09_23.Posts` p
     )
WHERE p.Tags LIKE '%android%' AND
      p.PostTypeId = 2 
LIMIT 10;
```

This should be faster.

Comment: As FYI: it will not be half of the cost! same bytes do not count twice, trice, etc. :o) so it will be the same as in first answer

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . BQ doesn't count each reference to the table?

Comment: Cost wise - you can self-join table multiple times and it will be only cost for the size of that table